# Unable to update to Capacitor to version 2.1.0

Tags: capacitor, ionic5

Currently, I am in Capacitor 1.5.2 in my Ionic 5 project. Following is the result of running `npx cap doctor`

```
   Capacitor Doctor   

Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 2.1.0

  @capacitor/core: 2.1.0

  @capacitor/android: 2.1.0

  @capacitor/ios: 2.1.0

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli 1.5.2

  @capacitor/ios 2.1.0

  @capacitor/android 1.5.2

  @capacitor/core 1.5.2
```

I have followed [this document](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/workflow#4-update-the-native-project) and run all the commands but only the `ios` got updated with a few audit issues. I have tried multiple times but unable to update cli, core and android. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I don't trust the update command, better do `npm install @capacitor/cli@latest`, or even uninstall first and reinstall

Comment: I was able to reinstall the cli and core but still unable to update Android from @capacitor/android 1.5.2 to @capacitor/android: 2.1.0. Tried both npm update @capacitor/android and npx cap add android after deleting the android folder.

Comment: and `npm install @capacitor/android@latest`? you don't have to delete the android folder to update capacitor, in fact, you shouldn't delete the android folder, ever

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. Please put your answer as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm update` respects semver, so it will never update to latest Capacitor if you are in v1.

Instead, use `npm install @capacitor/android@latest` (replace android with other capacitor package names you want to update)